# Pre-commit hook (husky + pretty-quick) doesn't work

Tags: prettier, husky

I've configured prettier and pre-commit hook like before but in my new project husky doesn't run before any commit!

Below is part of the project `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...,
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try setting HUSKY_DEBUG environment variable to 1 and running commit. This might provide some clues as to why the hook doesn't run.

Comment: Did you find the reason for it to not be running?

Comment: @PaulMoers Unfortunately not!

Comment: @MohammadRezaGhasemi, just FYI, for me it was that I was using husky v5 which doesn't support the package.json entry anymore.

Comment: Is that still happening?
run `npm ls husky`
`npm ls pretty-quick`

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue again. Maybe it's related to the forgotten ```.prettierrc``` file.

Answer (score 6):

I was running into the same problem but i'm using husky `^5.0.9`. 
Then i read the [docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=install) that you need to run `npx husky install`.
That fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

In pre-commit, use npm in front of pretty-quick

```
npx pretty-quick --staged
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use  `"husky": "^2.7.0", "prettier": "^1.18.2", "pretty-quick": "^1.11.1",`